# Performance of calling native code by either a P/Invoke wrapper or running a process in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have some native applications we have written in c++ and compiled to executables. .exe ect.

We need to run this in a service from c# and I am wondering if it makes any difference to create wrapper project that makes it easy to call it from c# either by a c++/CLI project or just p/invoke, or to just to start a process that calls the .exe file as we would do from command line?

Ofcause its easier to consume from c# if its just taking a namespace and call a c# function that takes care of things. Put I could as easy create that function that starts a process call to the command line exe and get the result that way.

Is there any performance difference to either method because that will most likely be the key factor for this as we can implement both ways easy.

Also using a c++/CLI wrapper makes transfer of variables easier.

Comment: There are performance differences, but it's very hard to judge whether or not they will matter. You cannot avoid the need for profiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ofcause its easier to consume from c# if its just taking a namespace
>   and call a c# function that takes care of things

It depends on *nature* of what your app is going to do using thet `C++` code. 
For sure it will be easier to debug.

The performance *should be* better in case of wrapper, as in case of EXE, you need to startup EXE, which may take some non so irrelevant time. In case of wrapper, there is perfromance bottleneck in transfering data between managed and unmanaged code, instead. Which, by the way, *should be* less then executable run.

All this depends on *concrete application lifecycle* and actually can be measured only by you, in your concrete context.

My choice would be:

- If calls are not so frequent, keep it like separate executable.
- On the other hand if calls are still not so frequent, but the amount of data you need to pass to and from calls are big enough, may consider wrapper. Here again choice of EXE may be again valid if your data is or can be file, so you just pass file paths to executable.
- If calls are frequent enough, use wrapper.

Repeat, those are just consideration that may or may not bring some *practical* benefit in your concrete case.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for and the conclussion is we will do it from case to case then. Its because we are running different algorithms on datasets and some algorithms comes as a exe, some python and some opencv. And if we can avoid it we really just want to run what ever people throw at us and save time on integrating it into our choice of language.

Comment: @pksorensen: yes, expecially if you are running native code, which is tightly coupled with complex tecnologies like OpenCV, were you have dozens of DLLs and LIBs, having all that stuff in single folder and calling it via exe may reveal as a best choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance difference. However, as with all performance tweaking, the key is profiling. Do it using the way that's easier, and check if its okay.

The main performance difference between the P/Invoke and C++/CLI way is marshalling, which is automatic in P/Invoke (with some customization).

Comment: Interesting with P/Invoke and C++/Cli - comments. I tend to do c++/CLI because I have the option to in between code. Like some managed paramters comes in and I can transform them the way I want before passing it to the native code.